# MongoDB update with layered JSON - how to efficiently? Dot notation?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, upsert, database

Mongodb has an update function, where it can increment pre-existing fields. However, I found that it could only update flat JSON. Whenever there's a JSONObject inside of a JSONObject, with a value I want to increment, I can't actually seem to do it. It will return this error:

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: Write failed with error code 14 and error message 
'Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {laneQty: { BOTTOM: 1 }}'
```

As you can see, I tried update incrementing laneQty.BOTTOM by 1. I don't want to write an algorithm to change every single layered json field into dot notation(like laneQty.BOTTOM), so is there a way to either turn the JSON into dot notation pre-upsert?

For now my general upsert function looks like this:

```
public boolean incrementJson(BasicDBObject json, String colName, ArrayList<String> queryParams, ArrayList<String> removeParams){
    /*make sure the game id AND the main player id can't both be the same. 
    If either/or, it's fine. We don't want duplicates.
    */
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(colName);
    for(int i = 0; i < queryParams.size(); i++){
        String param = queryParams.get(i);
        query.put(param, json.get(param));
    }
    for(String param : removeParams){
        json.remove(param);
    }
    return collection.update(query, new BasicDBObject("$inc", json), true, false).isUpdateOfExisting();
}
```

Is there any suggested upgrades to this code that could make it easily update layered json as well? Thank you!

By the way, it'll be very hard for me to hardcode this. There are a ton of layered objects and that would take me forever. Also, I am not in complete control of which fields are populated in the layers, so I can't just say laneQty.BOTTOM every single time because it will not always exist. Prior to upserting, the BasicDBObject json was actually a java bean parsed into BasicDBObject. This is its constructor if it's of any help:

```
public ChampionBean(int rank, int division, int assists, int deaths, int kills, int qty, int championId,
        HashMap<String, Integer> laneQty, HashMap<String, Integer> roleQty,
        ParticipantTimelineDataBean assistedLaneDeathsPerMinDeltas,
        ParticipantTimelineDataBean assistedLaneKillsPerMinDeltas, ParticipantTimelineDataBean creepsPerMinDeltas,
        ParticipantTimelineDataBean csDiffPerMinDeltas, ParticipantTimelineDataBean damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas,
        ParticipantTimelineDataBean damageTakenPerMinDeltas, ParticipantTimelineDataBean goldPerMinDeltas,
        ParticipantTimelineDataBean xpDiffPerMinDeltas, ParticipantTimelineDataBean xpPerMinDeltas, int wins,
        int weekDate, int yearDate) {
    super();
    this.rank = rank;
    this.division = division;
    this.assists = assists;
    this.deaths = deaths;
    this.kills = kills;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.championId = championId;
    this.laneQty = laneQty;
    this.roleQty = roleQty;
    this.assistedLaneDeathsPerMinDeltas = assistedLaneDeathsPerMinDeltas;
    this.assistedLaneKillsPerMinDeltas = assistedLaneKillsPerMinDeltas;
    this.creepsPerMinDeltas = creepsPerMinDeltas;
    this.csDiffPerMinDeltas = csDiffPerMinDeltas;
    this.damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas = damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas;
    this.damageTakenPerMinDeltas = damageTakenPerMinDeltas;
    this.goldPerMinDeltas = goldPerMinDeltas;
    this.xpDiffPerMinDeltas = xpDiffPerMinDeltas;
    this.xpPerMinDeltas = xpPerMinDeltas;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.weekDate = weekDate;
    this.yearDate = yearDate;
}
```

The participantTimelineDataBean is another bean with 4 int fields inside of it. I want to increment those fields (so yes it's only 2 layers deep, so if there's a solution with 2 layers deep availability I'll take that too).

Answer (score 0):

Use the dot-notation:

```
 new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("laneQty.BOTTOM", 1) )
```

Alternative quick&dirty solution: Just `collection.save` the whole document under the same `_id`.

Comment: "Also, I am not in complete control of which fields are populated in the layers, so I can't just say laneQty.BOTTOM every single time because it will not always exist." So I cannot simply just hardcode it. This way won't work. I don't want to collection.save different documents(I'm not even using the _id's to query) with same id because I will be getting easily over 1 million of these jsonobjects, and querying through 1 aggregate that gets updated is much better than going through and searching and getting 1 million jsonobjects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library:

https://github.com/rhalff/dot-object

For example if you have an object like this:

```
var jsonObject = {
  info : {
    firstName : 'aamir',
    lastName : 'ryu'
    email : 'aamiryu@gmail.com'
  },
}
```

then your node.js code would be like this:

```
var dot = require('dot-object');

var jsonObject = // as above ;-);

var convertJsonObjectToDot = dot.dot(jsonObject);

console.log(convertJsonObjectToDot);
```

Output will be as shown below:

```
{
  info.firstName : 'aamir',
  info.lastName : 'ryu',
  info.email : 'aamiryu@gmail.com
}
```

Please bear with me, this is my first answer on stackoverflow ever, since i was searching for the same thing and i found one solution to it, hope it helps you out.